# Actionscript reference to child element

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I reference to child element which is added during runtime?

Example code:

```
for(var i:Number=1; i<=5;i++){
    var mygroup:HGroup = new HGroup();

    var mybutton:Button = new Button();
    mybutton.label = "Browse Directory";
    mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,browsedirectory);

    var dirlbl:Label = new Label();
    dirlbl.text = "C:/some directory/";
    dirlbl.id = "path"+i;

    mygroup.addElement(mybutton);
    mygroup.addElement(dirlbl);
    mygroup.id = "group"+i;
    mainGroup.addElement(mygroup);
}

public function updatepath():void
{
    this["path1"].text = "new path";
}
```

When I tried to change the directory path in the label by calling `this["path1"].text = "new path";`, and it run into error

```
Error #1069: Property path1 not found and there is no default value.
```

How can I reference to those child element?

Thank you.

Comment: what does "this" refers to in your code?

Comment: 'this' is from the root.

Comment: Check these links [link1](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/05/20/objectcollector-accessing-dynamic-generated-flex-objects-by-id/) [link2](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/flex_reference_components_dynamic_runtime_creation)

Answer (score 1):

```
Caution, code not tested!
```

You could first check for all elements in a specific container (for your own knowledge):

```
private function displayChildren(element):void {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.numChildren; i++){
        var child = element.getChildAt(i);

        if (child != null) {
            trace ('position: '+i+' child name:' + child.name);

            for (var j = 0; j < child.numChildren; j++){
                displayChildren(child.getChildAt(j));
            }
        }
    }
} 

displayChildren(mainGroup);
```

This should output something like:

```
trace= position: 0 child name : "group1";     <- HGroup 
trace= position: 0 child name : undefined;    <- Button without id
trace= position: 1 child name : "path1";      <- Label
...
```

So following this, you should be able to access the label in following manner:

```
mainGroup["group1"]["path1"].text = "new path text";
```

-------------------- Update ---------------------------

What happens if you do the following?

```
var vgroup = mainGroup.getChildByName("group1");
if (vgroup != null) {
    trace(vgroup.id)
    var label = vgroup.getChildByName("path1");
    if (label != null) {
        trace(label.id)
        label.text = "change label text"
    }
}
```

Are you getting an output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All elements were in the container. But when I reference it with your example, it still drop the error `Error #1069: Property group1 not found on spark.components.VGroup and there is no default value.`

Comment: @user1995781 - If the solution worked - please accept the answer or let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks a lot for your help and your time. I really appreciate it. Actually what I was doing is to add element using Actionscript in flex project. Honestly, I didn't get it work with actionscript. So, my solution is use MXML Component instead, to add new elements into it.

Comment: No worries, if you got it solved then thats cool ;-)
Flex is quite a bit different then Flash but I do encourage using it over Flash for Desktop and more complex graphical applications that need to be developed ASAP.